# recover data from free space

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, data-recovery

I installed ubuntu 14.04 over my 13.10 but was trying to keep my data so I deleted all partitions (I didn't have a separate home directory) used manual partitioning and allocated 12 GB of my HD for installing the new OS. Everything went fine and 14.04 installed ok. But now I don't know how to recover the data in the free space that I left unpartitioned. I tried partitioning that space without erasing data and mounting it but when I opened it it was empty. How can get my data back?

Thank you

P.S. I have backed up my most important files but still it would save a lot of time if I could get the rest back.

Comment: the problem is that you deleted your partitions so your data is kinda lost..

Answer (score 2):

You have to try some Data Recovery tools which may help you to restore some of your old data.

[From R-tools Technology:](http://download.cnet.com/windows/R-tools%20Technology/3260-20_4-80773-1.html)

> R-Linux is a free data recovery and undelete utility for Ext2FS/3FS
>   (Linux) file systems. File recovery after power failure, system crash,
>   virus infection, or partition reformation, even for the different file
>   system. Unformat and unerase tool. The utility creates image files an
>   entire disk, partition or its part. Such drive image can be processed
>   like regular drive

You can [download 64 bit verion from here](http://download.cnet.com/R-Linux-Free-Recovery/3000-2248_4-10075543.html).

To install

```
sudo dpkg -i rli_en*.deb
```